# How to enable in-app purchase without Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, in-app-purchase, codemagic

I made an app with flutter.

I use the in_app_purchase plugin of flutter to implement inApp Purchases for Android and iOs.

It works perfectly for Android, but not for iOs. I think it is because I am not able to "Enable in-app purchase in Xcode" (https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb57be10e7), because I have no Mac.
I use Codemagic to sign and publish the App to iTunes Connect.

How can I enable in-app purchase in Xcode without a Mac?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Apple intentionally makes this very hard to do without a Mac. If you really need access to xcode, you can try making a virtual machine in VMWare or VirtualBox that runs Mac OS.
This is a fairly complicated process itself, and using flutter inside a VM will probably be incredibly slow. If you want to go this route, you can start here: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/run-mac-os-on-vmware-esxi/

I'd recommend borrowing a friends Mac, or renting a virtual Macbook. Creating a Mac OS VM is a huge pain in the ass just to add in-app purchases

Comment: I know rent a Mac in Cloud. I wanted to distribute the App with XCode, but now I got these errors: 'Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

No profiles for "*Bundle Identifier*" were found
Xcode couldn't find any IOS App development provisionning profiles matchting "*Bundle Identifier+".'

Do I have to plugin a iPhone to distribute the App to ITunes Connect?

Comment: Sorry, this is out of my realm of knowledge. Maybe this { https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/63957 }  will help you. I hope you find what youre looking for :)